# Add path to PHP that all PHP scripts can access

Tags: php

I am trying to execute a command in php script. I got a command sh not found. I added the path in  etc/sysconfig/httpd and it works for my php scripts in apache. How do I make it such that commands are available for scripts outside apache? I need to execute a php daemomn.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can run it in this format:

```
/path-to-your-php-install /path-to-your-script.php
```

example: `/usr/bin/php /home/whatever/public_html/script.php`

and I think you can determine where your php installation is by using `which php` command

Comment: if I do a service octave-daemon start, what should it be?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Actave and I might be misunderstanding the whole question. May be you need exec() or passthru() php functions?